# Add separator line in repsonsive Bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to add a separator line between menu items in the responsive Bootstrap navbar. I tried using `border-bottom`, but I need it to be inset on both sides. Here is what I am trying to achieve (the color is not the point here):

[image]

As you can see the line does not start from the edge of the screen.

How can I achieve this?

Here is my current code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in hidden-on-mobile"></span> Belépés</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user hidden-on-mobile"></span> Regisztráció</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the border to a pseudo element of the `a` in the tag, positioned with `position: absolute` and use the `left` and `right` values to account for the padding on that element so the border aligns with the text.

```css
.nav>li>a:after {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; left: 15px; right: 15px;
}

/* you don't need this - just for the demo */
.collapse {
  display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in hidden-on-mobile"></span> Belépés</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user hidden-on-mobile"></span> Regisztráció</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it does not work for me. Nothing shows up!

Comment: @BalázsVincze are you saying you don't see the red lines here? http://i.imgur.com/aJgqBNB.png